# How do i figure out the time complexity of these two small pieces of code?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I would like to know things about things and such

Comment: These are quite elementary exercises. Instead of just asking for the solution, please provide some information about how far you got with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for i ← 1 to 2n do` means `i` takes `2*n` different values, and for each of them, `j` takes an other `i` different values.

So overall, `s←s+i` is executed `O(2*n*2*n)` times, which is `O(n^2)`.

Same reasoning for the second example gives us `O(n^2*n^2) = O(n^4)`